# Javascript: Search html in an html string and wrap with a span

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an HTML string `targetContainerHtml` and an html element `el`. I want to search for `targetContainerHtml` in `el` and if it exists I want to wrap the html in a span.

I can get it to work with text or html that doesn't contain forward slashes. However if the html contains a anchor tag. It's not finding it. I think it's down to the RegExp escaping the slashes and trying to compare against html that hasn't been escaped.

```
var el = angular.element('body').find('.'+comment.selectionData.classID),

var containerRe = new RegExp('('+targetContainerHtml+')', "g");

el.html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(containerRe, '<span class="md-highlight-container">$1</span>');
});
```

I've tried to escape the slashes of `html` in the callback function but it never seemed to work. I'm not sure that's the right way to go about this.

My qustion is how do I get the `.replace()` function to match escaped html with non-escaped html?

Comment: Do you really have this issue with forward slashes? I played around with that stuff and had no problems with forward slashes - just with backslashes: http://jsfiddle.net/41ytjy7d/

Comment: You're right. I also forked your fiddle and added an anchor tag it worked. I will debug my code a bit more and update my question.